# How can I change options colors based on wether option is related to data or not in angularJS?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

Here's a sample code

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('mainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.options = ["hello", "ola", "bonjourno", "konichiwa"];
  $scope.selectedOption = null;
  $scope.selectedData = null;
  $scope.datas = [{
    id: "hello",
    value: "helloValue"
  }, {
    id: "bonjourno",
    value: "bonjourno value"
  }];
  $scope.selectData = function(str) {
    $scope.selectedData = null;
    for (var i = 0; i < $scope.datas.length; i++) {
      if ($scope.datas[i].id === str) {
        $scope.selectedData = $scope.datas[i];
        break;
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="mainCtrl">
    <select ng-options="d for d in options"
            ng-model="selectedOption"
            ng-change="selectData(selectedOption)">
    </select>
    <div>
      {{selectedData.value}}
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

My option is related to an array of datas in my final version of my app I will add or delete datas related to this option and sub-options. So to check if datas are related to that option I would like to change dynamically the options color.

So in this case option `hello`and `bonjourno`should be in let's say red.

I'm using AngularJS and know how to add class and change options color using JQuery and CSS but I don't really know the best way to achieve my goal with AngularJS.
Should I use directive if so How?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: The `ng-model` directive does not work on `<div>` elements. What are you doing there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the `option` elements inside the `select` to be coloured, it's easier if you instead used an `ng-repeat` on an `option`. This way, you can use the `ng-style` directive to apply the background colour you want.

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('mainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.options = ["hello", "ola", "bonjourno", "konichiwa"];
  $scope.selectedOption = null;
  $scope.selectedData = null;
  $scope.datas = [{
    id: "hello",
    value: "helloValue",
    color: "#f00",
  }, {
    id: "bonjourno",
    value: "bonjourno value",
    color: "#f00",
  }];
  $scope.getData = function (option) {
    for (var i = 0; i < $scope.datas.length; i++) {
      if ($scope.datas[i].id === option) {
        return $scope.datas[i];
      }
    }
  };
  $scope.selectData = function (option) {
    $scope.selectedData = $scope.getData(option);
  };
  $scope.getColor = function (option) {
    var data = $scope.getData(option);
    return data != null ? data.color : 'inherit';
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="mainCtrl">
    <select ng-model="selectedOption"
            ng-change="selectData(selectedOption)">
      <option ng-repeat="option in options"
              ng-value="option"
              ng-style="{ background: getColor(option) }">{{ option }}</option>
    </select>
    <div>{{ selectedData.value }}</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

If instead you want the entire `select` element to be coloured based on the current selection, it'd simply be a matter of adding the `ng-style` alongside the use of `ng-options`.

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('mainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.options = ["hello", "ola", "bonjourno", "konichiwa"];
  $scope.selectedOption = null;
  $scope.selectedData = null;
  $scope.datas = [{
    id: "hello",
    value: "helloValue",
    color: "#f00",
  }, {
    id: "bonjourno",
    value: "bonjourno value",
    color: "#f00",
  }];
  $scope.getData = function (option) {
    for (var i = 0; i < $scope.datas.length; i++) {
      if ($scope.datas[i].id === option) {
        return $scope.datas[i];
      }
    }
  };
  $scope.selectData = function (option) {
    $scope.selectedData = $scope.getData(option);
  };
  $scope.getColor = function (option) {
    var data = $scope.getData(option);
    return data != null ? data.color : 'inherit';
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="mainCtrl">
    <select ng-options="d for d in options"
            ng-model="selectedOption"
            ng-change="selectData(selectedOption)"
            ng-style="{ background: getColor(selectedOption) }">
    </select>
    <div>{{ selectedData.value }}</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

In both of the examples above, I've stashed the colour inside the data. For a small number of options like your example, you could simply hard code the colour choice based on option directly into the HTML if you don't want to add more metadata to your options.

#### Edit

To avoid the linear searches (i.e. `getData`) for the corresponding item in the `datas` array whenever `selectedOption` changes, you could transform the array into a lookup instead. This, of course, assumes you don't need `datas` in an array form for other purposes.

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.service('DataService', function () {
  this.get = function () {
    return [
      {
        id: "hello",
        value: "helloValue",
        color: "#f00",
      }, {
        id: "bonjourno",
        value: "bonjourno value",
        color: "#f00",
      },
    ];
  };
});
app.controller('mainCtrl', function ($scope, DataService) {
  $scope.options = ["hello", "ola", "bonjourno", "konichiwa"];
  $scope.selectedOption = null;
  $scope.selectedData = null;
  // Map data array into a lookup for convenient retrieval
  $scope.datas = DataService.get().reduce(function (lookup, data) {
    lookup[data.id] = data;
    return lookup;
  }, {});
  $scope.selectData = function (option) {
    $scope.selectedData = $scope.datas[option];
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="mainCtrl">
    <select ng-options="d for d in options"
            ng-model="selectedOption"
            ng-change="selectData(selectedOption)"
            ng-style="{
              background: selectedData != null ? selectedData.color : 'inherit'
            }">
    </select>
    <div>{{ selectedData.value }}</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, though there would be a solution without having to call `getData` twice but that is working so thanks again

Comment: Not a problem—I've included an edit in response to your concern about the `getData` calls. Hope that helps.

Comment: thank you very much. but could you edit one more time to check wether datad is here or not and not couloring all the options. Many thanks in advance.